# How to tune Play Framework application with proper threadpools?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I am working with Play Framework (Scala) version 2.3. From the docs:

> You can’t magically turn synchronous IO into asynchronous by wrapping it in a Future. If you can’t change the application’s architecture to avoid blocking operations, at some point that operation will have to be executed, and that thread is going to block. So in addition to enclosing the operation in a Future, it’s necessary to configure it to run in a separate execution context that has been configured with enough threads to deal with the expected concurrency.

This has me a bit confused on how to tune my webapp. Specifically, since my app has a good amount of blocking calls: a mix of JDBC calls, and calls to 3rd party services using blocking SDKs, what is the strategy for configuring the execution context and determining the number of threads to provide? Do I need a separate execution context? Why can't I simply configure the default pool to have a sufficient amount of threads (and if I do this, why would I still need to wrap the calls in a Future?)?

I know this ultimately will depend on the specifics of my app, but I'm looking for some guidance on the strategy and approach. The play docs preach the use of non-blocking operations everywhere but in reality the typical web-app hitting a sql database has *many* blocking calls, and I got the impression from reading the docs that this type of app will perform far from optimally with the default configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [...] what is the strategy for configuring the execution context and
>   determining the number of threads to provide

Well, that's the tricky part which depends on your individual requirements.

- First of all, you probably should choose a basic profile from the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools) (pure asynchronous, highly synchronous or many specific thread pools)
- The second step is to fine-tune your setup by profiling and benchmarking your application

> Do I need a separate execution context?

Not necessarily. But it makes sense to use separate execution contexts if you want to trigger all your blocking IO-calls at once and not in a sequential way (so database call B does not have to wait until database call A is finished).

> Why can't I simply configure the default pool to have a sufficient
>   amount of threads (and if I do this, why would I still need to wrap
>   the calls in a Future?)?

You can, check the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools):

```
play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 300
          parallelism-max = 300
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this approach, you basically are turning Play into a *one-thread-per-request*-model. This is not the idea behind Play, but if you're doing a lot of blocking IO calls, it's the simplest approach. In this case, you don't need to wrap your database calls in a Future.

To put it in a nutshell, you basically have three ways to go:

1. Only use (IO-)technologies whose API calls are non-blocking and asynchronous. This allows you to use a small threadpool / default execution context which suits the nature of Play
2. Turn Play into a one-thread-per-request Framework by drastically increasing the default execution context. No futures needed, just call your blocking database as always
3. Create specific execution contexts for your blocking IO-calls and gain fine-grained control of what you are doing

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, before diving in and refactoring your app, you should determine whether this is actually a problem for you.  Run some benchmarks (gatling is superb) and do a few profiles with something like JProfiler.  If you can live with the current performance then happy days.

The ideal is to use a reactive driver which would return you a future that then gets passed all the way back to your controller.  Unfortunately async is still an [Open ticket for slick](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/44).  Interacting with REST APIs can be made reactive using the [PlayWS library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS), but if you have to go via a library that your 3rd party provides then you're stuck.

So, assuming that none of these are feasible and that you do need to improve performance, the question is what benefit would Play's suggestion have?  I think what they're getting at here is that it's useful to partition your threads into those that block and those that can make use of asynchronous techniques.

If, for instance, only some proportion of your requests are long and blocking then with a single thread pool you risk all threads being used for the blocking operations.  Your controller would then not be able to handle any new requests, irrespective of whether that request needs to call a blocking service.  If you can allocate enough threads that this never happens then no problem.

If, on the other hand, you are hitting your limit for threads then by using two pools you can keep your fast, non-blocking requests snappy.  You would have one pool servicing requests in your controller and calling into services which return futures.  Some of these futures would actually be performing work using a separate pool of threads, but only for the blocking operations.  If there is any portion of your app which could be made reactive, then your controller could take advantage of this while isolating the controller from the blocking operations.